# Why is my GOTO statement not working (batch)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, goto

It always goes to the first lapel no matter what is the input

*I saw other posts with the same issue but none of the syntax mistakes they made were present in my script.*

Here is the script :

```
@echo off
cls

cd /d %~dp0

echo "Include files? [Y/N]"

set /p option=

if %option%=="Y" GOTO yes
if %option%=="y" GOTO yes
if %option%=="N" GOTO no
if %option%=="n" GOTO no

:yes
cls
powershell -command "iex \"tree /f\" > \"tree-filed.txt\""
GOTO end

:no
cls
powershell -command "iex \"tree\" > \"tree-folders.txt\""
GOTO end

:end
cls
echo the tree list was created.
pause
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There's no need to call tree from powershell

Comment: As the above comment notes: Why `powershell -command` and `iex`? Why not just write `tree` or `tree /f`? Why go through the trouble of spinning up a PowerShell instance that you don't even use? All it does is slow down your script.

Comment: I would advise you read the help for commands you are trying to use. The `IF` command has an `/I` option that will help you reduce your code.

Comment: the reason i used PowerShell with iex is the same issue as this question [Command Prompt “tree” shows Unicode in console but outputs to file in ASCII](https://superuser.com/questions/1056614/command-prompt-tree-shows-unicode-in-console-but-outputs-to-file-in-ascii)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[rifteyy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444547/45375) is effective,  but some background information may be helpful:

- As [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) notes, **an `if` conditional either requires *both* sides to be *either* (double-)quoted *or* unquoted**; that is, both `if %option%==y ...` and `if "%option%"=="y" ...` work:

  - The ***double-quoted* form is *more robust*,** as it also handles values with *metacharacters* such as `&` correctly, but the match must be *exact* with respect to presence or absence of spaces.
  - Conversely, only the *unquoted* form is forgiving of leading and trailing spaces; e.g. `if %option%==y ...` still works if the user entered   `y`   rather than just `y`.
- You can use **`if`'s `/I` option** to **make the comparison *case-insensitive***, which obviates the need to check for `y` and `Y` separately, for instance. `help if` shows more information.
- **`tree.com` is a stand-alone executable** that can be called from *any* (Windows) shell, so there is ***generally* no good reason to call *PowerShell* (`powershell.exe`, which is expensive)**, given that you can invoke `tree` directly from your batch file - though you may need PowerShell to control the *character encoding* of the output files.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - As an aside: Inside PowerShell there is *no* need for `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`), which [should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); the best way to invoke an external executable such as `tree.com` fundamentally works the same as from `cmd.exe` (see below).
  - If you *do* need PowerShell, call it as follows, for instance:
    `powershell -command "tree > tree-folders.txt"`

Therefore, a streamlined version of your batch file would look like this (`cls` commands omitted):

```
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"

:prompt
echo "Include files? [Y/N/Q]"

set /p option=

if /I "%option%"=="y" GOTO yes
if /I "%option%"=="n" GOTO no
if /I "%option%"=="q" GOTO :eof
goto prompt

:yes
tree /f > tree-files.txt
GOTO end

:no
tree > tree-folders.txt
GOTO end

:end
echo the tree list was created.
pause
```

---

As [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) points out, the standard **[`choice.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/choice)** utility offers a **simpler prompting solution**:

```
choice /c ynq /m "Include files?"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto yes
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 goto no
goto :eof
```

`choice.exe`:

- is case-insensitive *by default* (use `/CS` for case-sensitivity)
- accepts only a *single* input character from the user, which *instantly* exits the prompt (no <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress required), with the `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable set to the `1`-based position of the character in the list of permitted characters passed to `/C`

  - Note: The above deliberately uses, e.g., `if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1` rather than `if ERRORLEVEL 1`, because the latter uses *equal-or-greater* logic, which would require you to *reverse* the order of the branching statements.
- automatically validates the input (beeps if an invalid character is typed)

See `choice /?` for more information.

---

<sup>[1] However, you do need PowerShell if **the command's output contains *non-ASCII* characters** and you want the output redirection (`>`) to create UTF-16LE ("Unicode") files (Windows PowerShell) or (BOM-less) UTF-8 files (PowerShell (Core) v6+). Using `>` from `cmd.exe` results in *OEM*-encoded files, based on the console's code page, reported via `chcp`. Alternatively, you could switch the console code page to (BOM-less) UTF-8, via `chcp 65001`, but that wouldn't work with `tree.com`, because it is too old to support this code page. By contrast, it would work with the output from `dir`, for instance.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You must use brackets in IF statement also, if you did not, it will automatically do the actions under the IF statements.

```
@echo off
cls

cd /d %~dp0

echo "Include files? [Y/N]"

set /p option=

if "%option%"=="Y" GOTO yes
if "%option%"=="y" GOTO yes
if "%option%"=="N" GOTO no
if "%option%"=="n" GOTO no

:yes
cls
powershell -command "iex \"tree /f\" > \"tree-filed.txt\""
GOTO end

:no
cls
powershell -command "iex \"tree\" > \"tree-folders.txt\""
GOTO end

:end
cls
echo the tree list was created.
pause
```

Comment: It worked thanks! I can't believe I didn't see the quotes.

Comment: Rifteyy, the quotes are **not** required but are most certainly a best practice for string comparison.  What needs to be understood by the user is that the comparison is a literal comparison. All characters must be present on each side of the comparison for it to evaluate to TRUE.  The quotes are used in the comparison but are technically only needed to help preserve space and special characters in the comparison.